# Pandas DataFrame Map With Custom Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First DataFrame

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Original Invoice ID' : ['IN-11','IN-12','IN-13','IN-14','IN-15','IN-16'],
                    'ORDER ID' : ['123','123','123','456','996','864'],
                    'ASIN' : ['ABC','ABC','ABD','KSF','HKS','AJK']})
```

Second DataFrame

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Inovice ID' : ['IN-C-45','IN-C-46','IN-C-47','IN-C-48'],
                    'ORDER ID' : ['123','123','456','864'],
                     'ASIN' : ['ABC','ABC','KSF','AJK']})
```

I want to map Original Invoice ID in second dataframe using ORDER ID and ASIN value match.

Intresting Case When Duplicate orderID and ASIN in first dataframe then map original invoice id line by line

> Output:

| Invoice ID | ORDER ID | ASIN | Original Invoice ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IN-C-45 | 123 | ABC | IN-11 |
| IN-C-46 | 123 | ABC | IN-12 |
| IN-C-47 | 456 | KSF | IN-13 |
| IN-C-48 | 864 | AJK | IN-16 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a mistake in the provided output (IN-14 instead of IN-13).

Anyway, IIUC, you want to merge on your keys in order of the rows. For this you need to create another key for the order:

```
cols = ['ORDER ID', 'ASIN']
(df2.assign(key=df2.groupby(cols).cumcount())
    .merge(df1.assign(key=df1.groupby(cols).cumcount()),
           on=cols+['key'], how='left'
          )
    .drop('key', axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
  Inovice ID ORDER ID ASIN Original Invoice ID
0    IN-C-45      123  ABC               IN-11
1    IN-C-46      123  ABC               IN-12
2    IN-C-47      456  KSF               IN-14
3    IN-C-48      864  AJK               IN-16
```